# SPSS Syntax for computing a variable from different variables

Tags: spss

I have a test with multiple versions. Some appear of the questions are in all versions, some in only part of the versions, and some are unique in each version. Here is a demo:

```
examinee testversion q1 q2 q3 q6 q7 q8 q10 q11
1          1          1  2 3  2
2          2          2  1 1      1 
3          3          2  2 2         2
4          4          1  1 1   1        2
5          5          2  1 1      1          2
```

I want to compute the final score on the test, which is a mean of all questions on the test (accroding to the version).

I could do it with "DO IF" but I have 30 different versions, so this seems very long.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work: `compute testScore=mean(q1 to q11).` ?

Comment: You are right, of course. Following yur answer, I understood that my problem is a bit different. I will close this question and open another one.